# .page background-color won't change in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering why the background-color for .page in my CSS doesn't run. I would like a white background for the contents of my page but instead it remains transparent.

I think the link is working properly, as 'body' in CSS is working fine. However, changing anything in the .page doesn't change anything in the browser.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* Global Content Formatting and Styles */

body {
  color: #575c7a;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #515673 url(../images/background_gradient.jpg) repeat-x 0px 0px;
}
.page {
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale = 1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Lynda.com | Creating a Responsive Web Design</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/screen_styles.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/screen_layout_large.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:50px) and (max-width: 500px)" href="css/screen_layout_small.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:501px) and (max-width: 800px)" href="css/screen_layout_medium.css" />
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

  <header>

    <a href="#" class="logo"></a>

  </header>

  <article>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. <a href="#">Duis aute irure</a> dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

  </article>

  <div class="promo_container">


    <div class="promo">
      <div class="content">
        <h3>Promo Heading Here</h3>
        <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
        <p><a href="">Visit our blog</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="promo">
      <div class="content">
        <h3>Promo Heading Here</h3>
        <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit est laborum.</p>
        <p><a href="">Read the article</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="promo">
      <div class="content">
        <h3>Promo Heading Here</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit sed do eiusmod tempor inci did unt.</p>
        <p><a href="">Learn more</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>

  <nav>

    <a href="#">About Us</a>

    <a href="#">Services</a>

    <a href="#">Portfolio</a>

    <a href="#">Contact Us</a>

  </nav>

  <footer>
    &copy; Your Organization Name
  </footer>


</body>

</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You never use .page class at all.

Comment: @dfsq - or more accurately, it never uses the `page` class (note the removal of the `.` - that's for css descriptors, _not_ for class-names in the html)

Comment: As mentioned above it's because you've not used the class `page` on any HTML element.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're telling about overriding body's css rules in `<body class="page">`.

But you're having background as image in the body tag you are not overriding the body's background by using background-color in `.page` but adding meaning you have both background-image and the background-color. So, just use `background` to override that background:

```
.page {
    max-width: 980px;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;/* to override the background from body*/
}
```

Comment: I would assume due to the fact OP has applied a background image to body, that his intention was to use a class that wraps the content to apply a white background. So—If I follow all he needs to do is wrap the contents in another div with a class of `page`. However assumptions are never great!

Answer (score 0):

You're doing everything great so far.
You just need to combine the two scripts.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <style>
body {

    color: #575c7a;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    background: #515673 url(../images/background_gradient.jpg) repeat-x 0px 0px;

}

.page {
    max-width: 980px;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
}
    </style>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale = 1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Lynda.com | Creating a Responsive Web Design</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/screen_styles.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/screen_layout_large.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:50px) and (max-width: 500px)" href="css/screen_layout_small.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:501px) and (max-width: 800px)" href="css/screen_layout_medium.css" />
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>

    <body>

        <header>

            <a href="#" class="logo"></a>

        </header>

        <article>
            <h1>Welcome</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. <a href="#">Duis aute irure</a> dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

        </article>

        <div class = "promo_container">


            <div class = "promo">
                <div class="content">
                    <h3>Promo Heading Here</h3>
                    <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                    <p><a href="">Visit our blog</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class = "promo">
                <div class="content">
                    <h3>Promo Heading Here</h3>
                    <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit est laborum.</p>
                    <p><a href="">Read the article</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class = "promo">
                <div class="content">
                    <h3>Promo Heading Here</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit sed do eiusmod tempor inci did unt.</p>
                    <p><a href="">Learn more</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>

        <nav>

            <a href="#">About Us</a>

            <a href="#">Services</a>

            <a href="#">Portfolio</a>

            <a href="#">Contact Us</a>

        </nav>

        <footer>
            &copy; Your Organization Name
        </footer>


    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by adding a div around everything from the first `body` tag to the ending one and styled that with what you have for `.page` I'll add an example soon.

http://jsfiddle.net/L7va61oy/